# String Constant Pool

Tags: java

Me está constando bastante entender cómo funciona exactamente el concepto `String constant pool`.

¿Si creamos un objeto con `new` se crea un objeto en el heap y una referencia en la pool pero no un objeto?

¿Si creamos un objeto con `""`, se crea un objeto en la pool (no en el heap) pero no una referencia?

Answer (score 0):

A mi [Este enlace](http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/06/19/the-string-constant-pool/) me lo aclaro bastante. Pero esta en inglés. (aunque solo viendo los diagramas es bastante explicativo.

Con new crea un Objeto, y desde la variable hace referencia al objeto creado.

```
Sring s = new String("Hola");
```

Por otra parte solo con comillas es un tipo primitivo (es como int o Integer y boolean o Boolean)

```
String s = "hola";
String s2 = "hola2";
```

s y s2 si haces equals o "==" son iguales pues su contenido es el mismo. 
Si por el contrario usas el objeto String.

```
String s = new String("hola")
String s2 = new String("hola")
```

Ambos objetos no serán iguales, pues la comparación la hace entre objetos, y cada objeto tendrá su id (creo que con .equals() si te reconocería como iguales por el comparator que tiene, pero con "==" no)

Comment: Eso, cojones que no me salia xD

Comment: pero me sigue quedando una duda con =" se crea un objeto en la pool o se crea un objeto en el heap y una referencia en la pool la cual se reutiliza cuando se hace otro =" con el mismo literal? Es decir en el heap se crean objetos y en la pool referencias?

Comment: "El heap es el espacio de memoria en tiempo de ejecución que se usa para almacenar las instancias de clases, objetos y arrays". "El String Const Pool es un espacio especial donde se guarda una colección de referencias de donde se sitúan los objetos string". Me surgen dudas, al buscar tanta precisión pero creo, (y digo solo creo) que los objetos String se guardan en ambas dos siempre. Aunque, según el post que he puesto, da a entender que en el String Const Pool solo se guarda la referencia cuando no es un "new"